# Adapting Launch Screen storyboard to launch images with fixed sizes

Tags: ios, image, storyboard, screen, launch

I have an application for medical calculations and analysis that utilizes dozens of screens for data entry, each with carefully spaced entry and display fields. The app has two versions of each input screen, one for pre-iPhone X screen dimension (640x1136 ratio), and one for iPhone X screen dimension (1125x2436 ratio). In the LaunchImage section of the current Assets.xcassets scheme for launch screen images, I have a black png image that is 640x1136 pixels entered into the Retina 4, Retina HD 5.5", and Retina HD 4.7" slots, and a 1125x2436 pixel image image entered into the iPhone X / iPhone Xs slot. By placing images in this way, the OS automatically preserves the needed screen layouts, regardless of the size of the iPhone screen, even though I have a compiler warning that two of the launch screen images are the wrong size.

With the upcoming requirement to use a launch screen storyboard, I am unable to find, after extensive research, any way to preserve the crucial functionality that I have had to date, using the size of the launch screen image to enforce formatting dimensions. I understand the intent of the launch screen storyboard to simplify support for multiple devices with different screen shapes and sizes, but in my particular case, the new requirement introduces a very significant problem. Am I missing something, or is there a way to use the new launch screen storyboard in the manner that I have been using launch images?

Comment: The purpose of the launch storyboard requirement is to ensure that the full screen size is used on all devices. You will need to ensure that your app performs correctly regardless of the screen size.

Comment: The current method of using launch images works perfectly for my purposes, since I create two basic layouts for each view in my app, using the smallest screen size for the dimension, and the OS automatically scales up the display for the device size to fill the screen. I want to replicate that behavior with the launch storyboard, as required by Apple after June 30, 2020.

Comment: You can't.  Your app will need to deal with the native resolution of each device after June 30